# Can the vibrating notification when I get a text and using my phone work differently when locked?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, vibrate

I find it a little annoying if I am on phone and get a vibration for a text message. It's enough that I see the notification banner, i do not need it to vibrate too.

I want the vibration only when locked, not when unlocked.

Is there a setting for this on iOS 14?